# jenkins conditional matrix

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I need to run some Selenium tests on multiple platforms with multiple browsers and I didn't figure out how to configure the matrix for the multi-configuration project. What I want is to exclude Safari testing on the Windows node. Here is the matrix which I need to have:

```
                   Firefox Chrome IE  Safari
 Windows (slave)     x       x    x     -
 Mac (slave)         -       -    -     x

 'x'=test, '-'=ignore
```

For the execution part I can write a python script which will issue the proper commands based on the current OS

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In job configuration in **Configuration Matrix** category there is a checkbox **Combination Filter**. Add the following there:

```
!(label == 'Windows' && browser == 'Safari')
```

Assuming that *label* and *browser* are the right names of the variables you are using. If still in doubt, press "?" right of the text field. There is a very good help text there.

Comment: Yes, found it. Just wanted to post the solution.